# Missing end with declare, set and uuid

Tags: mysql

I want to salvage + hash in SHA512 passwords, for training, but I have an error and I really don't know why I have it and where it is.

Here's my procedure :

```
delimiter |
create procedure insert_user(in vuser varchar(35), in vpassword binary(64))
begin
    DECLARE salvage binary(16);
    SET salvage = uuid();

    DECLARE salvagedpassword  varbinary(100);
    SET salvagedpassword = concat(vpassword, salvage);

    DECLARE hashed binary(64);
    SET hashed = select SHA512(salvagedpassword);

    insert into tbl_user(username, passowrd, salvage_key)
        values(vuser, hashed, salvage)
end|
```

The error show's up at the coma right after uuid();
It says : missing end

Thank you for you help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    delimiter |


        drop procedure if exists insert_user |
        create procedure insert_user(in vuser varchar(35), in vpassword binary(64))
    begin
        DECLARE salvage binary(16);
        DECLARE salvagedpassword  varbinary(100);
        DECLARE hashed binary(64);

        SET salvage := uuid();
        SET salvagedpassword = concat(vpassword, salvage);
        select  password(salvagedpassword) into hashed;

        insert into tbl_user(username, password, salvage_key)
                      values(vuser, hashed, salvage);
    end|

    delimiter ;
```

Some notes:

- all `declare` should goes before any assignments
- there is no SHA15 function. You can use `password("plain_password")`
- we have mistyping in column name `passowrd` in insert
- i've added `drop procedure if exists` to make script re-executable

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! 
Clean and straight to the point :)                                                                Instead of using the password() function, I used, after few searches, the Sha2() function.
So :
 
   select SHA2(salvagedpassword, 512) into hashed;